# favicon not loading correctly

Tags: html, image, twig, href

Yes, I know this question has been asked many many times 
but I can't get to the bottom of this.

Adding a favicon is harder then I thought.

I am using twig and there are a lot of options I found.
Here are some.

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="{{ asset('public/imgs/logo.jpg') }}"/>

 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpeg" href="{{ path('public/imgs/logo.jpg') }}"/>

 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="/my-project/public/imgs/logo.jpg"/>
```

And many more..

as you can tell im struggling a bit over here..

Here is my folder strucure, which might help.

[image]

Comment: What does the rendered html show?

Comment: Well i added the logo to the "page" as well as the favicon. All i get is the. "its there but the path is wrong" icon ...

Comment: Your rendered html should show `/imgs/logo.jpg` as the path.

Comment: Okay going just for imgs/logo.jpg works, could you enter it as a answer and  explain why ? Im not quite sure ...

Comment: because only the the content of public folder is accessible through the browser.